# How to use Auth Token to fetch Google Tasks (REST API) on Windows phone

Tags: c#, rest, oauth, google-api, windows-phone-8

After getting auth token with required permissions, I am trying to access user's tasks.

Request URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/%40default/tasks?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Code to Make request:

```
    public void FetchTasks(string url)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
        httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishedWebRequest), httpWebRequest);
    }

    private void FinishedWebRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var httpWebRequest = ar.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
        var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(ar);
        byte[] responseByteArray= new byte[200];
        httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream().Read(responseByteArray, 0, responseByteArray.Length);
    }
```

Response

```
    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Login Required",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Login Required"
 }
}
```

Do I need anything else as part of request headers along with auth token in the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `Authorization` HTTP header to a valid `access_token` for the user whose tasks you'd like to access. Assuming you've completed the OAuth 2.0 dance and have a valid `access_token`, you can set the header by changing `FetchTasks()` to something like this:

```
public void FetchTasks(string url, string accessToken)
{
    var httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
    httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishedWebRequest), httpWebRequest);
}
```

Also, it looks like you're accessing the APIs using HTTP directly. Managing OAuth 2.0 tokens can be a bit cumbersome, You may want to investigate using the [official Google .NET API client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) which takes care of a lot of the heavy lifting for you.